# how can search faster in more than column in database using php

Tags: php, mysql

If user type keyword in search box I want engine to search in more than 4 column this take long time if can suggest another solution to fast this search as it search in more than 80,000 rows

```
$kay=$_GET['kay'];

<?php
$search_query = "select * from product where 
                             sku LIKE '%$kay%'
                            or mfr LIKE '%$kay%'
                             or manufacturer LIKE '%$kay%'
                               or LongDesc LIKE '%$kay%')";
?>
```

Comment: Firstly are each of the specified columns keys? Secondly, adding a covering index can speed things up so maybe look at those too

Comment: use fulltext indexes and fulltext search or better in your case: use something like https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch

Comment: it's a select *. Covering could be a disaster

Comment: show us your schema from a cut and paste, we can clean it up, and show you how to do joins

Answer (score 0):

The kind of search you have specified -- an `OR` sequence of `col LIKE '%value%'` clauses -- is the very slowest way anyone can imagine to search a MySQL table.  Why?  The promiscuous wildcard search `LIKE x` where `x` starts with  `%` can only be satisfied with a full scan.

Switch to `FULLTEXT` search. You can read about it on the MySql documentation web site.

There was a recent article about an extension to PostgreSQL that exploits hundreds of GPU cores running in parallel to do searches; that might help too.

Comment: seems like if they knew how to hang data by manufacturer id's, none of this would be a problem. Now we are off building a server farm

Comment: i use full search text but i must write all keyword not part of it as in like can you help me